# Como jogar um componente do layout pra cima?

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa tarde estou fazendo um app para estudos, e estou me deparando com um pequeno problema não chega a ser um bug, mas vamos lá, essa é minha tela inicial:

Como está na print abaixo, tenho um relative layout que tem nota 1 com sua edittext e peso com sua edittext.

quando eu clico no + um que é um Imagebutton ele entra no setonclicklistnner e seta visivel pro outro relative layout que esta logo abaixo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa parte que está circulada de vermelho é outro elemento que esta dentro de um relative layout que tem seu próprio id, nesse x ele seta invisible pro nota 2, ficando como estava na imagem dois...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora depois de explicar, minha dúvida é como que faço para que essa parte em branco aonde fica o outro relative layout soma ? como se não tivesse nada ali, e que o resultado e o somar fiquem perto do nota 1?

meu código do layout é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Nome da Matéria:"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Nota 1:"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"


        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView

        android:text="Peso"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/textView3" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
       />

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
         />

 <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:background="#fff"
     android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
     android:src="@drawable/plus_one"
     android:id="@+id/more1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/lig1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Nota 2:"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView

        android:text="Peso"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/lig1.1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        />

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/closerlig1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close_box_outline"
            />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Somar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rogers,

Você precisa entender a diferença de **invisible** e **gone**.

Se você usar o `android:visibility="invisible"` o layout continuará ali, porém invisível, então o espaço dele continua.

Agora se você usar o `android:visibility="gone"` o layout irá remover essa parte dali, tirando até o espaço branco.

Exemplo no java:

```
id_do_seu_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

e pra fazer voltar a aparecer no layout:

```
id_do_seu_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: ata obrigado eu não sabia, do .gone o visible e invisible eu sabia vlw a ajuda!

Comment: Ainda bem que eu consegui te ajudar antes de trancarem a questão...kkk Que bom que deu certo!